# fix footer position

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, webkit

I am trying to fix footer at bottom in iPad using the code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var offsetY = window.pageYOffset;
   var winHeight = $(window).height();
   $('#footer').css({top: (winHeight+offsetY-60)+'px'});   
});
```

where 60 is the height of footer. Its working fine but while scrolling (untill not finished) the footer's top position does not change, is there any way I can now that scroll has started? so that I can move the footer immediately or hide it while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using only CSS don't use jQuery for that

```
#footer{
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    height:20px;
    width:100%;
    background:#999;
}
/* For ie 6*/
* html #footer{
    position:absolute;
    top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
```

Comment: I thought this URL Helps you : http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/new-mobile-safari-stuff-in-ios5-position-fixed-overflow-scroll-new-input-type-support-web-workers-ecmascript-5